# How to find the object length using camera in android

Tags: android

i want to find the object length using camera . I have search a lot and i have found 
relation between distance & view angle.
  Formula  angle= arctan(d/2f)
but i m frustrated and not find any relative code. so please suggest me the working 
code in order to find the object height using camera. if distance from the object is 
know then how to find the object length 
Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you find the distance? How would you adjust for perspective? You need to define your problem better, otherwise I don't see how you can do this in a general way.

Comment: actually distance is enter by user so i know the distance but perspective part i m not clear

Comment: You would need to know how far the object is from the camera. Theoretically, you can autofocus the camera and then read the focus distance back. However, I've never found an android camera that gives a meaningful answer when queried for the focus distance.

Comment: What if an object is at an angle, but leaning directly towards, or away from, the camera?

Comment: You also need to know the field of view of the camera. If it has a wideangle lens, the object appears smaller. You can do this with Camera.Parameters.getVerticalViewAngle().

Comment: Camera.Parameters.getVerticalViewAngle() from this i get field of view angle ?

Comment: Yes. And I had to write this sentence because it wouldn't let me post just "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

```
verticalViewAngleDegrees = myCamera.getParameters().getVerticalViewAngle();
heightOfObjectFillingImage = 2 * userSpecifiedDistance * tan(toRadians(verticalViewAngleDegrees/2));
approxHeightOfObject = verticalPixelsOfObject / verticalPixelsOfWholeImage * heightOfObjectFillingImage;
```

I'm not confident that the trigonometry is the best that I could do, but that is a first approximation.

Comment: right now i m try this code if it works then i accept it & thanks emrys

Comment: how to find the 'verticalpixelofobject' and 'verticalpixelsof wholeimage' please help me

Comment: verticalPixelsOfWholeImage is the length in pixels of the whole image provided by the camera. verticalPixelOfObject is the number of pixels of that image which are occupied by the object you're trying to measure.